# Questions about mathematicians in the workplace

Tags: support, allowed-questions

Where should I address questions such as "What kind of tasks do people specializing in FEM work on?" or "Do you need to know a lot about computer architecture to work with large scale optimization?" and similar questions regarding the jobs/careers of mathematicians in industry? They're not about mathematics so they don't belong here, but they don't belong in meta either. Academia seems like a stretch as well.

There must be loads of people dying to get answers to questions like these (I know I am).  Is there a site for such questions?

Comment: If people are dying, surely it can't be from lack of answers about mathematicians in the industry. And if there are people dying from that, surely it can't be more than a handful of them. :-)

Comment: A handful of REALLY tiny people might be a very large number.

Comment: FEM and various large-scale computational issues are usually found on [scicomp.se]. You may want to investigate first whether they will consider your question appropriate for their site. Look around the site, read the Help Center on-topic page, maybe ask on their Meta.